# Trouble accessing Sketchup Features to SKP Toolbar in ArcMap 9.3?

Tags: tools, google, sketchup

I am having trouble getting the Sketchup plugin to work in 9.3. I have installed plugin into the correct location, been able to locate the proper .dll, but when I add it, and scroll down to where it should be, it doesn't appear. Does anyone know how to get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: What plugin are you using? ArcSketch? Or this: http://www.gsd.harvard.edu/gis/manual/arcgis2sku_fp/index.htm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, this plugin only works till ArcGIS 9.2

Answer (score 0):

The plug in works fine in ArcGis 9.3. Have not tested with 9.3.1.  You have to turn off UAC prior to installing the plug in (Vista, W7). You will have to reboot after turning UAC off then install the plug-in and turn UAC back on.